# Participate in Winter Bash 2017!

Tags: discussion, winterbash

As you may have noticed, the top bar on this site (and every other Stack Exchange site) has a new icon button that looks like an ice crystal. This button is available for the duration of **Winter Bash**, a yearly event during which you can earn **"hats"** by participating in the site.

Below are a few examples of hats you can earn:

- "Taco Tuesday Any Day": post three answers that get at least three upvotes each.
- "Identification Division": earn a [silver badge](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=silver).
- "Too cool": vote seven times via the app.
- "Like Clockwork": visit the site on 10 consecutive days.
- "Fascinator": do a search on the site on three consecutive days.

There are [many **other hats**](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) and [a few **secret hats**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340/340816) (which Stack Exchange users quickly figure out). When you earn a hat, you can position it over your avatar.  Of course, participation in this "hatarchy" is entirely optional; you can [**opt out** (and opt in again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304428/340816) at any time.

Winter Bash 2017 will end on 3 January 2018, after which all hats will disappear and everything will return to normal.

After last year's Winter Bash, our site got an "honourable mention" on the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/09/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/):

> A big congratulations goes out to Language Learning, as it only took 2 users to unlock the ["Just Here for the Hat"] hat, with [one user having 18](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/800/christophe-strobbe) of the distinct hats.

Let's see if we can repeat this in this year's Winter Bash!

Update: Here is the [**leaderboard**](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/languagelearning.stackexchange.com) for our site.

**Note**: As of 11 April 2018, this question is locked in order to prevent the Community User from bumping it up to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Winterbash 2017 is now over. On our site, 35 users collectively managed to earn a total of 60 hats.

[image: Winterbash 2017 leaderboard: 35 users from this site have earned a total of 60 hats!. Top users: Christophe Strobbe (8 hats), bytebuser (4 hats), fi12 (4 hats)]

The hats are gone now, but we can have another go at them in 11.5 months!

**Update**: [Farewell, Winter Bash 2017!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/10/farewell-winter-bash-2017/) on the Stack Overflow Blog (10 January 2018).